# jQuery - toggleClass() needs to start closed on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, toggleclass

Is there a way to make a menu that is closed by toggleClass() be closed automatically after refreshing the page?

The button that calls toggleClass() works perfectly. The session also remembers if the menu is hidden, so it performs the closing animation upon refresh. Is there an easy way to have the menu hidden when refreshed instead of performing the animation?

For further clarification, here is a [quick video I took of the issue](http://youtu.be/beObuj9GpPs):

```
initialize: function()
    {
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('sidebar.open') == 'false')
        {
            this.toggle();
        }
    },

    toggle: function()
    {
        var self = this;

        $(this.sidebarEl).toggleClass('active');

        _.each(this.contentEl, function(el)
        {
            $(el).toggleClass('active');
        });

        sessionStorage.setItem('sidebar.open',
                                $(this.sidebarEl).hasClass('active'));
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the transition is a CSS transition, right? That's why you're only changing the class...

Think about maybe canceling the transition, and then re-appending it.

CSS

```
.notransition { /*class to cancel transition*/
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu nontransition">...</div> <!-- when the page is loaded, use nontransition... -->
```

JS

```
initialize: function()
{
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('sidebar.open') == 'false')
    {
        this.toggle();
    }
    $(this.sidebarEl).removeClass("nontransition") // Then, delete nontransition, and allow the transition to work
},
```